# how to debug an event listener

Tags: html, html5-history

Kindly help in debugging an event listener. I have written a popstate event listener to window object.

```
window.addEventListener('popstate',function);
```

The popstate event should be triggered when a browser back button is clicked but how however it get triggered when i add history using HTML5 history api.

```
history.pushstate();
```

How to debug an event listener which triggered the event or previous step of execution using firebug or other developer tools. Kindly guide me as I am new to UI development.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get this information from the call stack if you put a breakpoint in your callback?

Also, note the docs indicate that popstate can be called more often then your question indicates:

> The popstate event
>
> A popstate event is dispatched to the window every time the active history entry changes. If the history entry being activated was created by a call to pushState or affected by a call to replaceState, the popstate event's state property contains a copy of the history entry's state object.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history